# Autogenerating command documentation with twisted and Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, buildout

I have a project where I use buildout to generate a number of cmdline tools, and Sphinx to generate documentation.

Is there a way in which I could write documentation near the definition of the code for a cmdline, then have Sphinx generate documentation for all commands in one page, using docstrings from the code for each command?

Comment: In general you can use the autodoc sphinx extension to create documentation from docstrings.... Not sure exactly what you mean by 'Generate cmdline tools' - Are you talking about code generation? Are they defined at the point you run your sphinx build?

Comment: Well. I have a system built in python. Its entry points, i.e. the commands that it makes available for use from commandline, are scattered around the code, and I then use buildout to create binaries that call these functions. I would like to collect the docstrings of all these functions in one place to create a list of commands with documentation. And this I would like to do automatically.

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution is to use "autofunction" (see [autodoc documentation](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html#module-sphinx.ext.autodoc)) to document your code. For example with a `.rst` file like this:

```
Command line tools
==================

.. autofunction:: mypackage.tools.do_something
.. autofunction:: mypackage.importtasks.import
.. autofunction:: mypackage.feed_the_cat
```

This'll document them like functions, which might not look as nice.

Another solution is to generate a proper `.rst` file from the docstring yourself. You can generate it into the sphinx directory and use it from there. As an example you can look at a [README.rst I generated](https://github.com/reinout/tools/blob/master/tools/README.rst) for a collection of tools (console_scripts entry points like yours, btw) and at [the script that generates the README](https://github.com/reinout/tools/blob/master/generate_python_docs.py).

You basically iterate over a bunch of files and add the relevant `.__doc__` items to a text file. I couldn't find how to use `setuptools` or `pkginfo` to get my hands on the `console_scripts` entry from the `setup.py`, but that's something you can do if needed in a custom script :-)